# Python org-mode babel output: column headers misaligned

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, python

I'm trying to view some rows of a pandas data frame. Is there a way to prevent the ">>> ..." from appearing before the headers, so that column names are aligned with the data?

```
#+NAME: simulate-data
#+BEGIN_SRC python :results output :exports code output :session p1
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt

def makeSim(nHosps, nPatients):
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    df['patientid'] = range(nPatients)
    df['hospid'] = np.random.randint(0, nHosps, nPatients)
    df['sex'] = np.random.randint(0, 2, nPatients)
    df['age'] = np.random.normal(65,18, nPatients)
    df['race'] = np.random.randint(0, 4, nPatients)
    df['cptCode'] = np.random.randint(1, 100, nPatients)
    df['rdm30d'] = np.random.uniform(0, 1, nPatients) < 0.1
    df['mort30d'] = np.random.uniform(0, 1, nPatients) < 0.2
    df['los'] = np.random.normal(8, 2, nPatients)
    return df

discharges = makeSim(50, 10000)
discharges.head()

#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS: simulate-data
: 
: >>> >>> >>> >>> ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... >>> >>>    patientid  hospid  sex        age  race  cptCode  rdm30d  mort30d       los
: 0          0      19    1  55.909740     3       84   False    False  5.211757
: 1          1       2    0  81.362813     1       60   False    False  7.442538
: 2          2      14    0  55.769465     3        5    True    False  5.851072
: 3          3      32    1  75.530266     3       79   False    False  8.721435
: 4          4       5    1  94.081585     1       64    True     True  5.895088
```

Answer (score 1):

My advice is to use ob-ipython instead. It does not have the issue you describe. The original is at https://github.com/gregsexton/ob-ipython. I have made a lot of improvements to it here: https://github.com/jkitchin/scimax/blob/master/scimax-org-babel-ipython.el.

Comment: ob-ipython solved my problem. Thanks John!